# NetSuite search to list customers not trading in last 12 months

Tags: search, formula, netsuite

I'm looking to provide a list of Customers in NetSuite who have NOT traded in the last 12 months (fiscal year) using the saved search functionality.

Comment: Hey Andrea! Check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

in the saved search criteria add the following entries

1. Date of last sales  - is not empty
2. Date of last order  - is not empty

you can also add another criteria for Transactions Field : Date and specify the timeline.
it will give you a list of active customer with orders/sales for your specified time period.

I hope this works for you.